# How to calculate quantity of all slices of array consisting N elements?

Tags: algorithm

Given array of `N` elements `A = [a1, a2, ..., aN]`. Slice is any sequence of adjacent elements. Like

```
[a1], [a1,a2], [a1,a2,a3], ... , [a1, a2,...,aN],[a2,a3], [a3,a4], ....
```

How to calculate count of all slices of the array? 
Is there a formula to get quantity?

Answer (score 1):

As a slice is determined by a starting and ending index, this is the same as asking how many distinct pairs can be picked from *n+1* elements (counting the 0<sup>th</sup> and n<sup>th</sup> index), where the order of the pair is not important.

That is counting [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), and the formula for *"n+1 select 2"* is: *n(n+1)/2*.

NB: This does not count empty slices. If those are to be counted also, and empty slices should be counted separately if their index is different, then this is counting multi-sets of 2 (as start/end index then can be equal). Then you should add an additional *n+1* to the above result.

Answer (score 0):

Let `S(n)` is a count of all slices of array of n elements.
Then `S(n) = n*(n+1)/2`.

Proof using mathematics induction approach.
1. Base `n = 1`

```
A = [a1]
```

number of slices is 1. `S(1)= 1*2/2 = 1`
2. Let `S(n) = n*(n+1)/2`
3. Check `S(n+1)=(n+1)*(n+2)/2`
   Array of `n+1` elements is

```
[a1,a2,...,aN,a(N+1)]
```

It has slices of array of n elements `[a1,a2,...,aN]` plus new slices:

```
(a(N+1)), (a(N+1), aN), (a(N+1), aN, a(N-1)), ... , (a(N+1),aN,...,a1)
```

Count of new slices (having inside element `a(N+1)`) is `n+1`.
Hence count of all slices equals to count of slices of array of n elements plus `n+1`.

```
S(n+1) = S(n) + n+1 = n(n+1)/2 + n+1 = (n^2 + n + 2n + 2)/2=(n^2+3n+2)/2
```

And substituting `n+1` instead `n` into formula in step 2 we have:
`S(n+1)=(n+1)(n+1+1)/2=(n+1)(n+2)/2=(n^2+3n+2)/2`. 
It proves the formula.

Also it gives useful relation:

```
S(n+1) - S(n) = n + 1
```

meaning difference of slices count for array of `n+1` and `n` elements is `n+1`.
Examples:

```
A1 = [a1], A2 = [a1,a2] S(1)= 1, S(2)=3 and S(2)-S(1)=2=1+1, n=1
A3 = [a1,a2,a3], S(3)=6, S(3)-S(2)=3=2+1, n=2
A4 = [a1,a2,a3,a4], S(4)=10, S(4)-S(3)=4=3+1, n=3
```